# how to get json string from angular $http post request

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, post, request

I am sending this POST, I want to see the string that get's sent in the request before I send it.

Here's [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0sld3lhVSHjT1SKl3FZb?p=preview)

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

I guess what I am trying to do is see the JSON string being sent to the server.

Comment: It's unclear. What you want to say ?

Comment: Touche, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are hitting the url with config option like this

```
var config = {
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    'dataType': 'json'
 };
var data = {
    name: 'intekhab',
    age:26,
};
$http.post('/admin/header', data, config).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Then you can see the data what are send. Open your browser `console` and click `network` then under `network` `click` your url what you have hit
And now see the look at `Request Payload under header tab`
There your data will be revealing what you have send to server.

And if you are not using config option like this

```
var data = {
        name: 'intekhab',
        age:26,
    };
    $http.post('/admin/header', data).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Then do the same as above only difference is where you have seen the data under `Request Payload`, now you will see the same data under `Form Data`

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you still unable to see let me know

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the feature in chrome. I can see all the data for any request being done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I think you want different handlers if the request succeeds or fails. You can do it in this way:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when it succeeds
  }).error(function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```