# Why json string going into http post request rather than javascript object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am sending some data using post request in angularjs
like

```
$http({
  method: 'POST', 
  url: url, 
  data: inputParams,
  headers: headers
})
.then(function succes(response) {
    successCallBack(response.data);
}
```

Data image:
[image]
Result in browser:

[image: Result in browser-AngularJS]

Similar I have in jQuery And its result is

[image: Result in browser-JQuery]

In case of angularJs look like data is going as JSON map, and on Backend server I am not able to read it from request body.

It may be duplicate of 
[how to get json string from angular $http post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367304/how-to-get-json-string-from-angular-http-post-request)

But still I am not able to fix my issue info avilable there ,can some tell me what I am missing.

Comment: This is merely a difference in how the browser chooses to visualise the data. Even with jQuery you're not sending an object which you can expand with a disclosure triangle; you're sending the same JSON, only the browser's debugger tools parse the JSON and allow you to inspect it conveniently. It's of course a valid question to ask why *that* is. Perhaps jQuery is sending a `Content-Type` header identifying the data as JSON, and Angular isn't?

Comment: Start by clicking the `view source` button to see the *actual* data being sent…

Comment: @deceze
view soucre:
{"appID":"passThrough","serviceID":"ONON","serviceType":"plainxmlserviceConnector","APIVersion":"1.0"}

And one more thing i am using same browser and same settings to view data , it's not about view data , it's about sending data to backend

Comment: @Martin thank you..:)

Comment: `view source` gives you that result *in both cases*?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is not sending the request as a JavaScript object, rather it is sending it as a form (like querystring) encoded string. Your developer tools are just decoding it and displaying it like an object.

It actually looks like:

```
appId=passThrough&serviceID=OFFOFF&APIVersion=1.0...
```

This is the standard format for traditional HTML forms.

As you can imagine this would not work well for nested objects.

```
var requestData = {
    planet: 'Earth',
    moons: [
        {
            name: 'luna'
        }
    ]
}
```

Form querystring encoding an object like this becomes problematic. This is why modern Http Client implimentations use JSON by default.

If you really want to use [form querystring encoding you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload#answer-11443066).

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
$http({
      method: 'POST', 
      url: url, 
      data: {
           data : inputParams
      },
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(function succes(response) {
        successCallBack(response.data);
    }
```

and in server side use req.body.data to do operations with your inputParams